# Form navigation issue

Tags: oracleforms

There are 2 forms example Form 1 & Form 2

By clicking a link on Form 1 -> Form 2 should be opened.

Form 2 also has validation and error message that should be displayed on opening form 2.

When navigating from form 1 to form 2, form 2 produces message popup but the message appears even before form 2 is rendered, i.e message s displayed on top of form 1 itself, on clicking ok then form 2 is rendered.

How to display the form 2 message after form 2 is rendered?

Comment: How exactly do you do that (a validation & raising the pop-up message)? Which trigger does it?

Comment: Validation through package invoked at form start up and pop-up using emessage.

Comment: OK, that's the first part of my question. What about the trigger? Which one is it?

Comment: @Littlefoot Trigger -> WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE